# non-defined variables in twig template

Tags: twig

checking for defined state of variables in twig can be annoying. Expressions like

```
{{ element.value is defined ? element.value : '' }}
```

are slightly to cumbersome to be easily explained to a non-programmer who might edit the twig file.

I would prefer a setting that tells twig to evaluate any non-defined field or variable to an empty string. Can this be achevied somehow?

Comment: Just use the filter `default`?

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
 {{ element is defined ? element.value : '' }}
```

or:

```
{{ element ? element.value : '' }}
```